# Is it possible to save and restore sound configuration in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I prefer to set my audio to stereo for YouTube, Spotify etc so my AVR can upmix the audio, but I need to set it to Dolby Atmos when using Netflix.

Is there a way to save and restore sound device configuration from the command line? I'm using Windows 11.